# Pass Button value into a function using angular

Tags: angularjs

I have one simple `nav-bar` ,In which when I click on tab I need to pass value of tab into a method.
I tried this but am getting `undefined`.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div>
<ul><li ng-click="displayValue(home)"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#"><span class="tabName" ng-model="home">Home</span></a></li></ul>
</div>
</body>

<script>
var app=angular
            .module('myApp', [])
            .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.displayValue= function (val) {
                    alert(val)
                }
            })
 </script>
```

Here I need to pass `home` into a method.

Comment: show us your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Pass your data as string `ng-click="displayValue('home')`.
For multiple tabs also you can pass like this.

Comment: Thanks ..I got it

Answer (score 2):

You cant pass the text as argument from the view. If you have define ng-model, then you can directly access it in the controller. Here is the updated code. I think it will clear all your doubt.

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp', [])
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.home = "Home";
        $scope.displayValue = function (val) {
            alert($scope.home);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul><li ng-click="displayValue(home)"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#"><span class="tabName" ng-model="home">{{home}}</span></a></li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ok If I have multiple tab means?then what would be the solution?

Comment: Are the multiple tabs being produced with ng-repeat?

Comment: @krish Here is the updated fiddle Which will clear your doubt regarding multiple tabs. https://jsfiddle.net/biswajit_rout/f1o0jj58/6/

Answer (score 1):

You should use your function name properly, it should be **`goSearch`** instead of **`displayValue`**

```
<li ng-click="goSearch(home)">
```

**EDIT**

If you want to pass the ng-model variable to a function, you need to have the value initialized.

```
 $scope.home = "Home";
 $scope.goSearch = function (val) {
            alert($scope.home);
 }
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.home = "Home";
     $scope.goSearch = function (home)
    {
        console.log($scope.home);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app='myApp' data-ng-controller='myCtrl'>
<li ng-click="goSearch()"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#"><span class="tabName" ng-model="home">{{home}}</span></a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-model="home"` on `a` element? I can't see how this will alert anything other than undefined

Answer (score 1):

Ok first you need to reference Home as a scope variable using double curly brackets "{{home}}". Then you need to define this scope variable in your controller. Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/ogpcvze7/

HTML

```
<div data-ng-app='myApp' data-ng-controller='myCtrl'>
<li ng-click="displayValue()"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#"><span class="tabName" ng-model="home">{{home}}</span></a></li>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.home = "Home";
        $scope.displayValue = function (home)
    {
        console.log($scope.home);
    }
});
```